# Is it true that $Y_{\tau} = \mathbb{E}[X_{\tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau}]$, where $Y_t := \mathbb{E}[X_{t} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t}]$ and $\tau$ is a ST?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{F} = \{\mathcal{F_t}\}_{t \in T \subseteq [0, +\infty)}, \mathbb{P})$ and a process $X_t$ that is not necessarily adapted to $\mathbb{F}$. Set $Y_t := \mathbb{E}[X_{t} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t}], \; \forall t \in T$. Let $\tau$ be a stopping time with respect to $\mathbb{F}$. Is it true that $Y_{\tau} =  \mathbb{E}[X_{\tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau}]$ a.s.?

If the time is discrete ($T = \mathbb{Z}_+$), it is almost obvious, I guess. As an adapted process, $Y_\tau$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. Moreover, since $T$ is countable, $\tau \in \{t_1, t_2, \dots\}$ a.s., thus (Lemma 8 from [this page](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/23/sigma-algebras-at-a-stopping-time)) we have a very nice representation for $\mathcal{F}_\tau$: $$\mathcal{F}_\tau = \left\{\bigsqcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cap \{\tau = t_n\}: A_n \in \mathcal{F}_{t_n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$
And then for an arbitrary $ A = \bigsqcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cap \{\tau = t_n\}, A_n \in \mathcal{F}_{t_n}$ we have
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_\tau I_A] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[Y_\tau I_{A_n \cap \{\tau = t_n\}}] =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[Y_{t_n} I_{A_n}] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[X_{t_n} I_{A_n}] = \mathbb{E}[X_\tau I_A] $$

But what if the time is continuous? In order for $Y_\tau$ to be measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_\tau$, $Y_t$ should be progressive. It is known that if a process is measurable and adapted, it has a progressive modification. $Y_t$ is measurable and adapted, and for every $t$ the random variable $Y_t$ is defined up to a set of probability zero, so we can choose $Y_t$ to be progressive. But is it true that $\mathbb{E}[Y_\tau I_A] = \mathbb{E}[X_\tau I_A]$, $A \in \mathcal{F}_\tau$?

Comment: in general $X_{\tau }$ is not a random variable, so the question is negative in the general setting

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your question is using the concept of the **optional projection**. Please refer
to C. Dellacherie $\&$ P. Meyer, *Probabilities and Potential B*, volume 72 of *North-Holland Mathematics Studies*.
North-Holland, Amsterdam,1982. Th. VI.43, p.103.